# Is there a way to access all of fs.watch listeners for a process?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, fs

I'm trying to implement a unit testing platform, a unit test automated runner, in a way that tests can be debugged, and this way involves clearing as many resources as possible between each test run, for example require.cache.

The problem I've been running into is that FSWatcher instances, if any are created by the unit tests and their associated code, are being duplicated for each test run creating an obvious memory leak, and printing big red warnings in the console. Is there a way to locate them from within the process to close them?

Answer (score 0):

http://nodemanual.org/latest/nodejs_ref_guide/fs.FSWatcher.html

You can call close() on a FSWatcher.

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I was asking. The problem is locating all the FSWatcher instances so that I can call close on them.

Comment: I think posting some code would help answer this... a memory leak is usually a sign of flaw in the system.

Comment: jibsales, I'm not dealing with any specific code, but with any arbitrary code that may place a watch on the file system. I need to be able to locate and remove it.

Comment: I've updated the question, in hope of clarifying it. My apologies if it was too vague prior.

Comment: are you not saving a reference to the file watcher when you create it?

Comment: My code doesn't create the file watchers. My code is the unit test platform - the unit tests that are ran by it are not my code, and they may or may not create the watcher instances. All I know is that if they do I need a way to find them somehow only having access to the global scope of the process, so global.process, global.require, etc.